# SQL Server 2019 replication problem after update to CU9

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2019

After update to CU9 for SQL Server 2019 (15.0.4102.2) (Linux Ubuntu 18), replication (snapshot) stopped working with errors:

```
2021-03-23 11:58:08.70 [0%] The replication agent had encountered an exception.
2021-03-23 11:58:08.70 Source: Replication
2021-03-23 11:58:08.70 Exception Type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.NativeSqlConnectionException
2021-03-23 11:58:08.70 Exception Message: memory mapped file write failed
2021-03-23 11:58:08.70 Message Code: 0
```

Do you have any suggestions? I've tried to recreate replication, restart mssql server. Nothing works.

Comment: I've worked a lot with **replication**, but never have encountered that error. Any chance [this post](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/replication-error-memory-mapped-file-read-failed) helps you?

Comment: Yes, I've worked a lot with replication too and it stopped working after update to CU9. It's production env and I don't want to rollback to CU8 to check if this is an issue. I've seen this post, not much more in google..

Comment: I encountered this error in the latest SQL Server image on Ubuntu running in a container and confirmed that it is not an issue when I rolled back to CU8. I haven't been able to find out anything else about it yet.

Comment: Still appears broken in CU11 (15.0.4138.2)

Comment: I've got a ticket open with MS, though they can't reproduce it yet.  One interesting bit was that the Clustered PK on my table wasn't an int, it was a varchar.  Putting it here in case that may help others.  Weirdly, I can do it command, but it starts when there's more than 6950 rows in the table - fewer, and it works , and the next entries look fine.

Comment: In my env, I can't replicate table with 1k rows... Please let us know if they reproduce this.

Comment: Guys, someone has any update or resolved issue?

Comment: @mbourgon, did they solve this in CU13 or 14?

Comment: @MarcinDziok crud, I forgot to post here!  I'm not sure when, but from MS on Nov 3 "This issue is going to be addressed in next CU’s for both 2017 and 2019. Our engineering team confirmed that this is related to MapViewOfFile() for bcp not working as expected."

Comment: For those looking to repro it, I don't know the specifics, but "I’m able to reproduce the issue using Adventureworks database", if that helps.

Comment: Thx, so we have to wait. Regards

Comment: Looks like it MIGHT be fixed in most recent CU for 2019. Hard to tell since there's no explicit KB for it: "Fixes the EXCEPTION_INVALID_CRT_PARAMETER dump that is generated on insert or update of wide replicated table." (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5007182-cumulative-update-14-for-sql-server-2019-67b00a61-4f30-4a36-a5db-b506c47e563b#bkmk_13966323

Answer (score 1):

They've fixed it in CU14. Already tested and it works.
Thx all for help.